# How many Saptrishis have been mentioned in scriptures? Which Yuga did they belong too?

Tags: rishi, yuga, saptarshi

Were there only seven Saptrishis? Were there any females amongst Saptrishis? Are they ever mentioned as doing parikrama around Sun or Earth? Have there been multiple sets of Saptrishis during various ages? During which Yuga did Saptrishis live?

Comment: Saptrishi is a position which changes after every manvantara.Still there are 7 saptrishis and after this manvantra next 7 ones will be alloted the seats.In billions of manvantra yes chances are there for femalr ones but not in the history we know.No they are still.Saptrishis disappear only after 100 years of brahma.Again the creation stars but particles are same

Comment: Have you seen the meaning of Sapta?

Comment: Hello @Saptrishi Welcome to Hinduism SE... Please limit your question body to a single question... If you have more than a single query, kindly post them as different questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple questions!

According to the Satapatha Brahmana, the Seven Rishis are

> गौतम, भरद्वाज, विश्वामित्र, जमदग्नि, वसिष्ठ, कश्यप and अत्रि; Gautama, VaradvAja, VisvAmitra, Jamadagni, Vashishtha, Kashyapa and Atri.

According to the Mahabharata, the names are

> मरीचि, अत्रि, अङ्गिरस्, पुलह, क्रतु, पुलस्त्य and वसिष्ठ; Marichi, Atri, Angiras, Pulaha, Kratu and Vashistha.

Manu adds three more names to these sevens and calls them 'PrajApati' or the progenitors of Mankind.So they must have belonged to the Satya-yuga (and seems immortal.)

There are NO females in them.

The are here not perceived as the stars and so the question of moving around the Sun or the Earth does NOT arise. There are seven stars called together as the Saptarshi-mandala though:

> In astronomy the seven Ṛiṣis form the constellation of "the Great Bear"

Reference : sanskritdictioary.com : https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%E0%A4%BF&lang=sans&action=Search